# Sass loop over nth items

Tags: sass, each

I have 4 list items that I each need a different background colour on.

I can put my 4 different colour variables in a Sass list and each through them as `$color` but in the content block of that loop I obviously need to specify which `<li>` I am talking about using `:nth-of-type` 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I'm not sure how to specify which `<li>` I need on each turn of the loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$colors: (#000, #F00, #0F0, #00F);
@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
   li:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
       background: nth($colors, $i);
   }
}
```

It produces:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: black; }

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red; }

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: lime; }

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: blue; }
```